# Is Using a Trigger for Monitoring purpose is correct approach

Tags: database, triggers

I am working on a requirement , say for example there is a Bank account , and in case if there is a credit or debt of 5000 Rupees on it , i need to send a SMS .

I am planning to use Database Triggers for this , please tell me if this is correct approach or not ??
If this correct approach , please tell me how to call a Servlet from a Trigger to do this operation ??

Thank you very much .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may or may not be the correct approach, depending on whom you talk to. You could get this to work if you wanted to, no doubt.

I personally wouldn't recommend it though because this is clearly business logic that is being pushed onto the DB. Why would you want to distribute business logic into different technologies? The right place IMHO is to have this within the same code that handles all other business logic.